# JSP page and Servlet reporting different session IDs

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I'm setting a bean with some data in a JSP page, but then in my servlet when I try to access the value, I get a null value back. I printed the session IDs in both pages and I'm getting different values. Does anyone know what might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling session.invalidate() anywhere in some code path that might be getting executed?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that your session is getting invalidated somewhere. If you do have `session.invalidate()` statements somewhere in your code, put breakpoints there and verify in debug mode if any of them is being hit.

You can also implement and set up a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) in your project. Implement the callback interface and add the implementation class to your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.xyz.AppSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Put a breakpoint within `sessionDestroyed` method and see when it gets hit in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that you opened a new question for this. This issue has been answered in the comments of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418469/using-jsp-bean-in-a-servlet). Here's an extract of relevance:

> Sessions are domain and context dependent. If the servlet listens on an URL of a different domain and/or context than the JSP, then it will indeed use a different session. You can however let different contexts share the same session by configuring the servletcontainer accordingly (in Tomcat, set `emptySessionPath` attribute of `<Connector>` to `true`). But you cannot share sessions among different domains due to security restrictions in HTTP spec.

The other cause is indeed that you explicitly invalidated the session by [`HttpSession#invalidate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29), but that would have been too obvious to spot in your code.